# How can I preview an exported table (PDF XeTeX) directly in Lyx?

Tags: lyx

I create my tables in Lyx. Example:

[image: Table in Lyx]

After using `Export -> PDF (XeTeX)`, the table taken from the PDF looks as follows:

[image: Rendered table as PDF]

Is it possible to generate a live preview of this rendered version directy in Lyx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Display and set "Instant preview" to "On". Select "Save".

Then select the table and go to Insert > Preview.

This works for me on Ubuntu. I have seen reports that some users have problems, mostly on Windows and Mac.

Note that there have been many improvements for Preview that will be part of 2.1.4, which will be released soon.

Also note that we hope to someday make it so you can easily enable preview for all tables without having to do the step of going to Insert > Preview for every table. See http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/1234

Comment: Thank you very much! I followed your steps but the table is not properly previewed. Please see this screencast: http://youtu.be/2evxSSE7rBA

Comment: @orschiro thanks for the screencast. It makes it easy to help. You selected the *inside* of a table. So that's why when you paste you paste its contents. You need to select the table itself. An easy way to do that is to put your cursor just to the left of the table, then do shift+right. Then go to Insert > Preview . For more of an explanation: LyX has the concept of "insets". The table is an "inset" just like e.g. a footnote. What you did was select the equivalent to the text *inside* a footnote instead of selecting the footnote itself.

Comment: This worked, thank you! Now I just have to find out how I can change the background of the previewed table to plain white.

Comment: @orschiro why? Is that because you've changed the LyX background?