# How can I change the default background colour in Lyx to plain white?

Tags: lyx

I would like to change the default background of all content (non-preview, preview) to plain white:

[image: Background colour in Lyx]

Comment: I don't avise you to change to white: such a high contrast is strenuous to the eye. There is some reason for publishers to print on cream-colour or ivory paper.

Answer (score 6):

You can customize colours in Tools --> Preferences --> Look & Feel --> Colors.

Different document elements have different colour settings. For example, the colour of the general text is defined by the colour called *background*, and that of equations by *math background*. Hence, you would have to consider which elements you want to have a white background, and change accordingly.

Comment: This does not affect the background colour of the live preview set from Look & Feel --> Display --> Display Graphics -> Instant Preview --> On

Comment: @orschiro Oh? Live preview of what exactly? I tested with an equation, and I think that is transparent, so the white background shows through.

Comment: @orschiro I did notice though that different elements have their separate backgrounds, equations for example use a different colour than the standard background.

Comment: @orschiro did you see my question at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254664/how-can-i-preview-an-exported-table-pdf-xetex-directly-in-lyx#comment610445_254666 ?

Comment: @orschiro If the tables keep the old background colour, try forcing a rerendering of the preview, e.g. by editing the text in one of the cells.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. just in case you're curious, this bug (that the old previews were kept after changing background color) was reported at [http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9684] and there is a fix that which will probably be in LyX 2.2.0.